# Deleting file from Google Drive Web API Explorer

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

Why cant I delete a file using Google Drive Web API Explorer [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/delete), I also tried with OAuth2 playground [here](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) , My file id is correct. Is it not possible from API Explorer or OAuth2 playground ? I knw its not possible in GDAA.I get an error as below-

```
403 Forbidden

- Show headers -

{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "forbidden",
"message": "File not mutable"
}
],
"code": 403,
"message": "File not mutable"
}
}
```

Comment: Show us you file id (you can replace some characters with a '.' so you keep your stuff private).

Comment: Also, if you go to web Google Drive and use 'rightclick>share>get shareable link' and get something like: 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1mQU..............WF4bGs/view?usp=sharing', is the string the same as the one you;re  passing in?

Comment: Thnx, this is my file id -0AMjIXSz0mKHSUk9PVA, which is retrieved thru GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AMjIXSz0mKHSUk9PVA by OAuth 2.0 Playground. But I cant delete it. Can u explain a bit abt replacing character with a ' . ' . One more thing, if I try this in browser- https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AMjIXSz0mKHSUk9PVA?key={MY_API_KEY}, I get "bad request,key invalid", How do I get API KEY for my drive?I tried with access token in this place but failed.

Comment: Just some people don't like to place the full file/folder IDs on a public display, so they would put  something like '0AMjI..........9PVA'. And I was mainly interested in the format of the ID, since some people confuse it with DriveId from GDAA. This is not your case, though. But the main thing is, I don't have an answer at this time. Sorry.

Comment: What scopes are you using when you try to delete?

Comment: It doesnt work with any scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive or any.. )